# How-To: a browser based, real time, shared memory inspection/debugger application

Tags: javascript, python, web, ajax

#### Background:

I have a C application running under Linux utilizing shared memory. I also have a debugger written in Python that can link to said shared memory and access individual variable values of global scope.

#### Question:

How can I develop a local browser-based application/page that, via my Python process, I can connect with in order to display near real-time variable values in a prettified form?

#### Usage:

I should be able to launch my background applications, then launch this server/client application in a browser, then be given an option to load a page with list of variables names (2-way communication), after which it simply should start displaying all the names with their values.

#### What I need:

Technical, process-flow solution, that utilizes solely Python if possible (understanding html/css/js/etc are necessary), and provides the ability to update the browser page's list of values automatically at >= 20Hz.

#### Additional details:

- It needs to update the page between 20-60Hz, preferably in order (e.g. 'time' may be a value and want to update as 1.3 -> 1.4 -> 1.5...
- Only needs to work with Firefox
- Linux-only development, don't care about Windows or Mac
- I don't want to use a real GUI app like QT/WX/GTK

Comment: Your question will probably get closed as too broad to be answerable, but some things you will need to consider: doing anything in a browser will not be anywhere close to the speed you want; using a browser, **you will be limited** in how you can communicate with anything outside of it (this is by design). That being said, you could create a small web service that feeds JSON through an AJAX call initiated by the browser page. I would not expect more than about 5, *maybe* 10 updates per second that can be displayed. Partial page updates **might** be faster.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where to start](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)**

Comment: Wow.. this is.. wow.. who do we bill?

Comment: Using JonathanEunice 's method below, and despite my utter novice in web-technologies, I successfully managed to print a list of my background C-application's "name: values (unit)" at >=20Hz easily to a local browser window. With this same approach and more tools I believe I should be able to do some near-live graphing etc with this same data. You can bill me if this app sounds helpful to you, @AndrewHoffman ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of a local web app is a good and appropriate one. I have built several of these, and they work well. They have very fast update times, and let me work with Web tools rather than the declining breed of GUI toolkits.

I recommend a [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)-based connection between your Python code and your web page/client/app. This will give you near-real-time update speed and the ability to communicate bi-directionally between Python and a JavaScript-based front-end/app. You can use whatever JavaScript frameworks or widgets you like. There are some quite good [graphing](http://c3js.org/examples.html), [plotting](http://dimplejs.org), and [visualization](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) frameworks for web apps these days--some better than what you typically see in GUIs, even.

There are an increasing number of ways to integrate WebSockets and Python. I prefer the [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) web app framework for its combination of simplicity and generality. You can run it natively (it has a built-in web server), atop Tornado, behind a real web server, etc. For a local app, you may want to review [this simple demo which requires no extra middleware](https://bitbucket.org/jeunice/flask-ws-example).

Comment: Beautiful! Using Flask and your demo as a starting point I was able to quickly produce a server application that using WebSockets I could connect to via my browser client, and use to display values at a very fast rate. This does satisfy my question regarding python usage, update rate, local browser app, and process flow. Now I just need to touch up how the internals work (AJAX/HTML/CSS/JS/JQUERY). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You might use an HTTP server library like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) (or perhaps [Wt)](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt), perhaps even in your C application, and use [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) techniques (perhaps with [Jquery](http://jquery.com/)) -and perhaps [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)- to periodically update the dynamic web page. FWIW, my [MELT monitor](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor/) is doing this.

Notice that web technology cannot *guarantee* any update frequency, in particular in the event of long latency (imagine the browser being in Australia, and your C application running in the middle of the USA with a *bad* internet connection between them). But if both the HTTP server program (e.g. your C application using `libonion`) and the browser are near (on the same LAN) you *probably* would be able to get 20Hz updates.

In my view, you might not need any Python or PHP code (by adding HTTP server ability in your C application with `libonion`). However, you need to become familiar with web technologies ([HTML5](http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/), [Javascript](http://www.javascriptsource.com/tutorials/), [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)) and [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). For that [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) -and other websites- is not perfect but has a lot of useful information.

If for whatever reason you still need to have a separate Python process, I'm sure you would be able to find Python HTTP server libraries.